# Make Screen reader read the tooltip content when it appears

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using bootstrap's `tool-tip` functionality.

I have a `button` and when it is clicked a `tooltip` appears. I am able to achieve this functionality by using `trigger` option of Bootstrap tool-tip plugin.

However, screen readers are not able to read the content of opened `tool-tip`.

I am trying to get screen readers read the content of the tool-tip once it appears.

So how to ensure the tool-tip content is conveyed by screen readers when the user presses the Enter key when the `button` has focus.

Can any one help me to achieve this functionality?

I am attaching the [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhBz1GfrXatwqJAMeCLs?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the aria role="tooltip" for this, is not well documented but you can read about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tooltip)

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" role="tooltip">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

[Updated Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/nltuNLBo1v6DneLqAihM?p=preview)